# How Do I Block an IP Address on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, ip, nat, blocking

I have configured Ubuntu machine as router. Steps of **NAT**   configuration are given below:

```
        #iptables -F
        #iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
        #iptables-save > /etc/network/iptables
```

Then kept this file location in rc.local

```
#vi /etc/rc.local

#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.  
#  
/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/network/iptables 
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution  
# bits.  
#  
# By default this script does nothing.
exit 0

#reboot
```

It works, Now I want to block an ip address. To do this, I have executed following command:

```
#iptables -A INPUT -s   69.171.229.11 -j DROP    
#iptables-save >  /etc/network/iptables    
#reboot
```

But it does not work.

`vi /etc/network/iptables` now look like this:

```
 # Generated by iptables-save v1.4.4 on Tue Feb 14 11:21:16 2012
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [870:97719]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [283:23151]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [461:28753]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE   COMMIT
 # Completed on Tue Feb 14 11:21:16 2012
 # Generated by iptables-save v1.4.4 on Tue Feb 14 11:21:16 2012
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [4914:3254723]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [2382:1222521]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4010:410041]
-A INPUT -s 98.137.149.56/32 -j DROP 
COMMIT
 # Completed on Tue Feb 14 11:21:16 2012
```

What am I missing to block an ip address?

Comment: After you execute this what is the output of `iptables -L -v -n`?

Comment: Are you trying to block the IP from connecting *to* the machine? Or from routing *through* the machine? The `INPUT` chain is only for packets that are delivered locally. (Check `ip route show table local` to see what is local.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to block an IP from using the MASQUERADE rule you need to put that rule in the `FORWARD` chain, not the `INPUT` chain.

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 69.171.229.11 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the sequence is not correct.

What you are doing with append is putting it on the bottom of the chain. IPtables stops after the first match. So it can be that the rule is matched just before it hits the block rule. Make sure the blocking rule is on top. You can use the -I option to insert it at a specific spot in your chain.

Comment: While it is true that the order of rules in iptables matters, by the looks of it he only has one rule in them. The rest are just the policies, which always are shown first with iptables -S and always are evaluated last.

Answer (score 0):

iptables-save does **not** make your iptables rules persistent, so they will be lost after reboot. Instead, what it does is it prints your current iptables configuration to STDOUT (see [manpages for iptables-save](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?iptables-save+8)). So after your reboot, your iptables should be empty.

You probably want to restore your rules from that file after a reboot. To do so, use

```
iptables-restore < /etc/network/iptables
```

See [manpages for iptables-restore](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?iptables-restore+8) on this.

---

As mentioned by Patrick, the rule

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 69.171.229.11 -j DROP
```

will only prevent packets from being sent to the router itself - they will still be forwarded through if they are addressed correctly. To prevent that, add the rule

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 69.171.229.11 -j DROP
```

FORWARD is applied to packets the router wants to forward, while INPUT is applied to packets that are addressed to the router itself.